# Wordpress cannot create .htaccess file, cannot add image, link in post on Centos7

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, server, centos7

I installed the new wordpress site on Centos7 server. After installing it does not automatically create wp-config.php file so I have to copy the settings manually. It also does not create the .htaccess file and I have to create it manually. The problem is that I can upload images but cannot insert them into the article. When adding the link to the article and saving it, report the error:

> **Forbidden**
>   You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/post.php on this server.

If there is no image link, the url in the post will still be saved normally. I have learned quite a lot to fix it but have not been able to handle this problem. Hope everyone helps!

*I am extremely grateful!*

Comment: check if there is any security  issue

Comment: I also think it is due to the security of centos7 but do not know the specific cause and the way to handle it

Comment: try turning off the ModSecurity in your cPanel to see if it corrects the problem

Comment: I tried before but did not fix this error :'(

Comment: Does this help when adding to htaccess <IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.